# Puppet invalid ressource

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I'm very new to DevOps tools and I'm starting to learn Puppet. I found this example at this link nice to start with for my purpose : configuring an Appache server with Puppet : http://blog.akquinet.de/2011/11/23/managing-an-apache-server-with-puppet/
But when running the code presented in the article I have the following error

Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Invalid resource type apache::vhost::proxy_http at /root/kmlunch.pp:17:1 on node learning.puppetlabs.vm

Maybe it's an obvious error, but I don't know how to fix it. Can you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: you are pulling a newer apache module then the one for which your document was written. In the meantime the resource apache::vhost::proxy_http has disappear. If I'm not mistaken, the proxy part was integrated in the vhost define.

Solution: use an other tutorial (a newer one).